# How do i get variables from general.php

Tags: config, settings

Within the config folder there is a general.php file with various vars which are site specific.

how do i get at these from within a plugin?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: its ok i found it - craft()->config->get('JsPath'); for example.

Answer (score 7):

```
craft()->config->get('JsPath');
```

Answer (score 7):

For Craft 3:

`Craft::$app->config->general->{var name}`

Answer (score 4):

It is considered best practice to use the public get methods, so while the Craft 3 answer is correct, you should try to get in the habit of calling the methods.

```
Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->varName
```

It looks more verbose, but generally best practice and follows the coding guidelines.

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/coding-guidelines.html#app-component-getters